# Porque deja de responder Visual Studio.?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, vb.net, devexpress, vs

Bueno les explico mi problema, Estoy trabajando en un proyecto web con el lenguaje de visual studio, ASP y controles de Dev Express el cual yo lo encontre ya avanzado y estoy añadiendo nuevas integraciones pero a la hora de estar diseñando ya sea agregando text box botones o realizar cualquier cambio hasta el mas minimo en la interfaz desde el Html se traba, visual deja de responder por 3 minutos y despues se recupera pero tambien me consume mucha memoria, lo veo en el Administrador de tareas que podria ayudarme ah agilizar oh terminar este problema.?
Espero puedan ayudarme Saludos

Comment: Empieza por desinstalar TODOS los plugins que tengas instalados. Reinicia VS Code y prueba si el comportamiento se repite. Por otro lado, esta pregunta no parece relacionada con [es.so], por lo cual podría terminar cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Sale ok Gracias

Comment: @ElTroll donde dice vs code????

Comment: a ver... visual studio no es un lenguaje, es una ide... capaz estas programando en vb.net??? luego.. dices que al modificar el html se traba.. que cosa se traba??? la ide?? esta reprocesando algo??? tendra que ver con deb express?? preguntaste en su foro?? asi como esta, no podemos mas que hacer mil conjeturas.. que ni siquiera sabemos si estan bien...

Comment: XD, se me olvida que existe esa cosa llamada Visual Studio. Tienes razón @gbianchi no dice Code por ninguna parte, excepto en mi comentario. Lamento que mi comentario no sea de ayuda. Si tienes otra pregunta, con gusto puedo ayudarte.

Comment: gbianchi lo que tu dijiste todo el mundo lo sabe. y claro que entendiste a lo que voy referido no hay que ser tan arrogantes, se que troll se equivoco no era VS Code, dime porque yo tendria la necesidad de corregirlo si su comentario lo comprendi bien oh solo por eso me voy a poner a decirle que visual studio es una cosa y VS Code es otra. De igual forma Gracias. Feliz Navidad my Friend.

Comment: @Brandon no entendi tu comentario... lo corregi y ahi quedo la cosa.. pero no entendi que fue lo que sabemos todos...